# What's wrong with my copy constructor?

Tags: java

Beginner in Java. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to write one of the constructors for a java project. I'm going to include most of the code to provide some context. This class is to be accessed by another file which holds the methods for a terminal menu.

```
// java class for keyboard I/O
import java.util.Scanner;

// declaration of the class
public class NumberList
{
    //integer constant that determines the size of the array
    public static final int MAX_CAPACITY = 100;

    //array to store the numbers        
    private double [] numbers;  
    //the number of valid numbers currently in the NumberList
    private int length;

    //default constructor that initializes array to size MAX_CAPACITY and initializes all
    //array values to 0, sets length to 10
    public NumberList()
    {
        numbers = new double[MAX_CAPACITY];

        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < MAX_CAPACITY; i++)
            numbers[i] = 0;

            length = 10;
    }

    //outputs the numbers in the NumberList to the 
    //standard output screen    
    public void print() 
    {
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
            System.out.println(numbers[i]+ ", ");

        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }



    //assignment constructor, initializes array to size 100,
    //initializes length to l and sets the first l values of the list to the     value n
    NumberList(int l, double n)
    {   
        numbers = new double[MAX_CAPACITY];

        length = l;

        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < MAX_CAPACITY; i++)
            numbers[i] = n;

    }


    //array constructor, initializes array to size 100, takes an array
    //as input and completes a deep copy (element to element copy) from the array
    //parameter to the numbers array 
    NumberList(final double[] a)
    {
        this.numbers = new double[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        {
            this.numbers[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
```

Everything above compiles nicely. Not sure if I'm on the right track or if a "for" loop is necessary.

```
    **//copy constructor, initializes array to size 100, 
    //creates a copy of parameter NumberList nl to the calling NumberList
    NumberList(final NumberList nl)
    {
        numbers = new double[MAX_CAPACITY];

        nl = new NumberList(MAX_CAPACITY);

    }**

    //returns the length of NumberList
    public int length()
    {
        int length = numbers.length;
        return length;
    }

    //returns the sum of the numbers in the NumberList
    public double sum()
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + numbers[i];
            }
        return sum;
    }
```

Grateful for any tips/ advice I can get.

Answer (score 3):

A copy constructor is just that: A *constructor*. So you're operating on a new instance freshly created for you. You don't want to create another instance, just set up `this`.

For instance, in your case, make the `numbers` of the current instance a copy of the `numbers` of the source instance, and copy `length`:

```
NumberList(final NumberList nl)
{
    this.numbers = nl.numbers.clone();
    this.length = nl.length;
}
```

---

*(With thanks to [Jorn Vernee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3699139/jorn-vernee) and [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) for pointing out `Arrays.copyOf` and `clone`, respectively. Went with `clone`.)*

Comment: A tip; you can use [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-double:A-int-) to copy `numbers`, which would be a little more concise.

Comment: @JornVernee: Thanks. I felt like `arraycopy` was really old-hat, but couldn't immediately think of the "modern" (circa a decade ago! wow) version. Updated. :-)

Comment: Or even shorter and as efficient: `this.numbers = nl.numbers.clone();`.

Comment: @assylias: Even better!

Comment: @assylias: Another reason why `clone` is more convenient, thanks. :-)